# GWTBootstrap3 / missing arrows in DateTimePicker

Tags: css, datetimepicker, arrows, gwtbootstrap3

I'm using the DateTimePicker in the ui.xml as follows:

```
<b:Label text="{messages.gwt_ui_from}" />
<b.date:DateTimePicker styleName="btn-block"
    ui:field="dtpFrom" format="dd.MM.yyyy" minView="MONTH"
    maxView="YEAR" autoClose="true" hasKeyboardNavigation="true" highlightToday="true"/>
<b:Label text="{messages.gwt_ui_to}" />
<b.date:DateTimePicker styleName="btn-block"
    ui:field="dtpTo" format="dd.MM.yyyy" minView="MONTH"
    maxView="YEAR" autoClose="true" hasKeyboardNavigation="true" highlightToday="true"/>
```

As you can see, the style is set to `"btn-block"`.

But the result is the following picture:

[image: DateTimePickerWithoutArrows]

How can I keep the style and still get the arrows back?

Thanks very much for any help!
Aurel

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone having the same problem I've had

The solution in my case was quite simple (after having searched for three days...)

```
<b.date:DateTimePicker styleName="btn-block form-control"
    b:id="dtpToId" ui:field="dtpTo" format="dd.MM.yyyy"
    minView="MONTH" maxView="YEAR" autoClose="true"
    hasKeyboardNavigation="true" highlightToday="true" />
```

Just add `form-control` to the `styleName` attribute of the DateTimePicker and enjoy the arrows.

Hope this helps someone!